# ApiController: Get with same argument but different return

Tags: c#, get, controller

I start implementing an ApiController. I have multiple get function with different arguments and various return types.

Actually, I have a service class and I implement a get function for every service one.

The issue is that I have now two functions in the same controller that take the same arguments but return different type. For example:

```
     [HttpGet]
     string Get(String item){ return "Test";}
     [HttpGet]          
     int Get(String entry){ return 2;}
```

I can't start compiling because Visual Studio says that these functions are similar. How can I proceed to solve this issue?

Comment: It's not possible to create a method with the same method signature, but a different return type. This is as designed in the C# specification.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to name the functions Get.

you can name them..

```
GetItem
```

and

```
GetEntry
```

Comment: Thanks,I tried to do it but when I launch the site say that there are multiple entries...

Answer (score 0):

Like others have said, you have to choose different names for your methods.

> Thanks,I tried to do it but when I launch the site say that there are multiple entries...

Well, if I request `GET mywebsite.com/MyController/123`, which of your two methods will be called?

You need to create two custom routes, one for each method, so ASP.NET will know which one to call. Add these to your `WebApiConfig.cs`

```
   config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "GetItem",
            routeTemplate: "api/MyController/Item/{item}",
            defaults: new {controller = "MyController", action = "GetItem"}
            );

   config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "GetEntry",
            routeTemplate: "api/MyController/Entry/{entry}",
            defaults: new {controller = "MyController", action = "GetEntry"}
            );
```

And call them by issuing GET requests to `MyController/Item/123` and `MyController/Entry/123`

Answer (score 0):

I am a little bit unsure why you need 2 Get methods who returns different results, that defies the principle of Get method for Web API. One Controller is supposed to return only one type of objects for its get method. That is why it is called Web API.

But again if you really need this then you can do this with one Get method and returning multiple data packed in an object -

```
public class WData{
    public string Item {get;set;}
    public int Entry {get;set;}
}

public class RQuery
{
    public string item { get; set; }
    public string entry { get; set; }
}


public IHttpActionResult Get ([FromUri] RQuery query)
{
    WData data = new WData();

    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpt(query.item))
        data.Item = "Test";

    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpt(query.entry))
        data.Entry = 2;

    return Ok(data );  
}
```

Something like this could work. I haven't tested the code though. But should work.